# What's a good title for firefighters?

Tags: single-word-requests, forms-of-address

When addressing police or jail staff, a lot of times you address them as "[Rank] [Last Name]", such as "Sgt. Smith" or "Lt. Reynolds".  If you don't know their rank though, you can resort to "Officer [Last Name]".  (Again, I'm just referring to police and jail guards there, not military.)

What's the equivalent for firefighters?  They have military-style ranks, but what if you don't know a firefighter's rank?

Comment: If you mistakenly refer to a military sergeant as "officer" you'll get a stern "I'm not an officer, I work for a living" response.

Comment: I think you can refer to them as "Fireman Jones".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were speaking to the firefighter, I would probably address him or her as *Sergeant (?) Jones*, with a rising inflection on Sergeant.  Then it is up to the firefighter to correct me.  *Actually, ma'am, I'm the fire captain.*  Or, *Actually, ma'am, I'm a Fire Officer*.  No one will be insulted at being called a sergeant, unless of course he is wearing insignia of a higher rank.

If I were writing about a particular firefighter, I would write: *I do not know his rank, but Fire Officer Jones bravely saved my cat, and I am grateful beyond words.*

According to [The Wall Street Guide to Essential Business St [sic]](https://books.google.com/books?id=MqdSIpKgEZMC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=generic+word+for+firefighters+and+police+officers&source=bl&ots=_KtPUggJ77&sig=Gn_mlvDZJdjNBwnjPUxxcaxullU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjItLehr7XXAhUO5mMKHTYpCcIQ6AEIQzAE#v=onepage&q=generic%20word%20for%20firefighters%20and%20police%20officers&f=false) *police* or *fire* should preface the rank if necessary to be clear. *... police Sgt...* or *...fire Lt....*

Comment: This might work where firefighters use military-style ranks. You'd come across as rather odd using *sergeant* [in the UK](http://www.ecfrs.co.uk/ranks/ranks.htm) where ranks go firefighter, leading firefighter, sub officer,station officer...